# How to get only the first element 'source' in each element 'audio'

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have an html in which inside each element `audio` there are one or at most two elements `source`, i.e.

```
<audio preload="auto">      
        <source src="/medias/SOUNDS/originals/mp3/M000001099.mp3"> 
        <span>Votre navigateur ne prend pas en charge audio.</span>
      </audio>
```

or

```
<audio preload="auto">      
        <source src="/medias/SOUNDS/originals/mp3/M000001099.mp3">
        <source src="/medias/SOUNDS/originals//mp3/M000001099.mp3">    
        <span>Votre navigateur ne prend pas en charge audio.</span>
      </audio>
```

My html contains many such elements `audio`. The below code will return the links from all `source`.

```
import requests
session = requests.Session()
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'}
r = session.get('https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/aimer', headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

[tag.attrs['src'] for tag in soup.select('.d_sound_cont audio > source')]
```

and result

```
['/medias/SOUNDS/originals/mp3/M000001099.mp3',
 '/medias/SOUNDS/originals//mp3/M000001099.mp3',
 '/medias/SOUNDS/originals/mp3/M000001099.mp3',
 '/medias/SOUNDS/originals//mp3/M000001099.mp3']
```

On the other hand, I only want to get the link from the first `source` in each element `audio`. Could you please elaborate on how to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `:nth-child(1)` to your CSS selector:

```
import requests
session = requests.Session()
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'}
r = session.get('https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/aimer', headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

print( [tag.attrs['src'] for tag in soup.select('.d_sound_cont audio > source:nth-child(1)')] )
```

Prints:

```
['/medias/SOUNDS/originals/mp3/M000001099.mp3', '/medias/SOUNDS/originals/mp3/M000001099.mp3']
```